# Android List Preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I have built the default SettingsActivity in Android Studio (v2.2.3).  I would like to change one of the settings to a ListPreference to allow the user to enter a family name and birth date.  (Also update and delete)  I have the following XML but I am not sure how to modify it to get what I want which is in the attached image file.

```
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="-1"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:key="example_list"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="Add Family Member" />
```

[Idealized Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDvRt.png)

Comment: You should use your own layout instead of build in `ListPreference`

Comment: Any pro tips or documentation to build custom listPreferences?  I was reading through the android docs and it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Just use Dialog with your own layout. No need to use `ListPreferences` at all.